# How to reference images from a diferent table C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two tables, `Libro` (books) and `Imagenes` (Images) where `Id` on `Libro` is referenced on `Imagenes` as a fk on `IdLibro` so that I have an image for each `Libro`.

I want to reference the image on a Bootstrap card but they are on different tables on the database, how do I do it?

Here is what I have

```html
@{
    foreach (var lib in Model)
    {
        <div class="card col-md-3 m-2" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => lib.Imagenes)" class="card-img-top" alt="There should be an image here">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">@lib.Titulo</h5>
                @switch (lib.Saga)
                {
                    case 0:
                        <h6> </h6>
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        <h6>Canción de Hielo y Fuego</h6>
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        <h6>Harry Potter</h6>
                        break;
                }
                <br />
                <div class="row m-2">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p class="card-text">$@lib.Precio</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="row m-2 position-absolute bottom-0">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/Home/Detalle/@lib.Id">Ver</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <a onclick="Agregar(@lib.Id)" class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="@lib.Id">Agregar</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: And you are accessing the database in which way?

Comment: I created a project on the solution that references the database, then referenced it on the one I'm working on.
Then I added the reference on the controller

I didn't posted all of the content on the page bcs they are a lot of lines and different files

Comment: And how does that solution reference the database?

Comment: I added an element (ADO.NET Entity Data Model) and added a EF Designer from a database from Microsoft SQL Server, then added the references from my project to the one that I have the Database on using the tools from Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Is it possible to enter Libro and Imagenes class code? Also enter your action codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure of your classes is as follows, you can easily access the Imagenes class values

```
 public class Libro
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     //........................
     public ICollection<Imagenes> Imagenes { get; set; }
 }
    
 public class Imagenes 
 {
     public int ID { get; set; }
     //..............................
     public int IdLibro { get; set; }
     public Libro Libro { get; set; } 
 }
```

in view

```
@{
    foreach (var lib in Model)
    {
       <img src="Url.Content(lib.Imagenes.FirstOrDefault().ImageUrl)" />
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, I was using the src incorrectly